# Error: Expected a right parenthesis in expression at (1) even with continuation &

Tags: debugging, fortran, parentheses

below is the equation code:

```
  f=2*(cz&
    +uu+ss)
```

Even with the continuation symbol `&`, I still get the error:

```
 164 |  f=2*(cz&
     |                  1
Error: Expected a right parenthesis in expression at (1)
```

How do I solve this bug?

Comment: You must show more code. We must know the surrounding lines and the file extension and the compiler command and flags you are using. Are you really sure it is free source form?

Comment: It has been solved, I need to add & a few space before the second line.

Comment: It can be solved by adding & at the end and front of the lines, also change the file name from*.f to *.f90.